# Compare text file with given 2 column names as input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 text files with the random column list.

File 1: `file1.txt`

```
ID|Name|Number|Date
1|John|991122|23-12-2017
2|Smith|889911|24-12-2017
3|Mak|776532|25-12-2107
```

File 2: `file2.txt`

```
Number|ID|Date|Name
991122|1|23-Dec-2017|John
889911|2|24-Dec-2017|Smith
776532|3|25-Dec-2017|Mak
987654|4|26-Dec-2017|Joseph
765551|5|27-Dec-2017|William
```

I want to do comparison between file1 and file2 based on specified 2 columns and want to store the result from `file2.txt` into the output file as `.txt`.

Expected Output File: `output.txt` Based on the specified columns `ID` and `Date`.

```
Number|ID|Date|Name
987654|4|26-Dec-2017|Joseph
765551|5|27-Dec-2017|William
```

**Note**: Column `Date` might have different(unknow) formats in any file.

Try:

```
file1 = 'E:\Python\File Comparison Files\File1.txt' 
file2 = 'E:\Python\File Comparison Files\File2.txt' 
file3 = 'E:\Python\File Comparison Files\outputfile.txt' 

with open(file1) as b:
    first_line_b = b.readline()
    print 'File1 Columns:', first_line_b

file1Column1 = raw_input('Enter File1 column1 name to compare:')
file1Column2 = raw_input('Enter File1 column2 name to compare:')


with open(file2) as a:
    first_line_a = a.readline()
    print '\nFile2 Columns:', first_line_a

file2Column1 = raw_input('Enter File2 column1 name to compare:')
file2Column2 = raw_input('Enter File2 column2 name to compare:')

#Following will do all data comparison, but not specified column
with open(file1) as b:
    blines = set(b)
with open(file2) as a:
    first_line = a.readline()
    with open(file3, 'w') as result:
        result.write(first_line)
        for line in a:
            if line not in blines:
                result.write(line)
```

The above code will compare complete data but not for specified column/field. As I want to compare based on passed two column from each file and store the result in the third file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` to do this efficiently

```
import csv

file1, file2, file3 = 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'
col_name = raw_input('Enter File1 column1 name to compare:')

uids = set()
with open(file1) as fo1:
    for row in csv.DictReader(fo1, delimiter='|'):
         udis.add(row[col_name])

with open(file2) as fo2:
    with open(file3, 'w') as fo3:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fo2, delimiter='|')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fo3, delimiter='|', fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            if row[col_name] in uids:
                continue
            writer.writerow(row)
```

`file3.txt` now should contain

```
Number|ID|Date|Name
987654|4|26-Dec-2017|Joseph
765551|5|27-Dec-2017|William
```

Comment: Does this work for specified column `Date` and `ID`?

Comment: I have updated the answer to compare the specified column. It can be one of Name, ID, Date or Number

Comment: It will not work with `Date`. Can you please check once?